# Can't update attribute after logging with sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I have a field `auth_token` which I want to generate a new token each time a user login.
So I write the line `(2)` but it doesn't work. The user login successfully but the field `auth_token` doesn't update.

Can anybody explain this?

```
if login(params[:email], params[:password])
  current_user.update(auth_token: 'sfd')   #(2)

  flash[:success] = 'Welcome back!'
  redirect_to root_path
else
  flash.now[:warning] = 'E-mail and/or password is incorrect.'
  render 'new'
end
```

P.S. I used `Sorcery` gem

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely to be a validation problem. Try to replace `update(...)` with `update!(...)` to see an error.